# How to do unindexed searches in OpenLDAP

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am trying to run a search on openldap database with a filter that consist of unindexed attributes but it is failing and not returning any result. When I check the openldap debug logs, I can see the log below:

**mdb_equality_candidates: (attribute1) not indexed**

When I add an index for attribute1 to slapd.conf as:

**index attribute1 eq**

then it works fine.

My question is, isn't it possible to run a search by filtering an attribute that is not defined as index?

Thanks

Comment: Evidently not. What's your objection to indexing the attribute?

Comment: When I google a bit, I can see some people doing unindexed searches this and seems this is somehow possible. Basically, I don't want to add index to fields that I don't use frequently for search operations.

Comment: What does your search filter look like?

Comment: it is like "attribute1=somevalue"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> isn't it possible to run a search by filtering an attribute that is not defined as index?

Yes it is possible. The server is merely logging the fact that you have done so. It hasn't refused to perform the search.

Comment: I do the same search with the same dataset with only one difference. In the first try I don't define the attribute that is in the filter as in index and I retrive an empty result set. In the second try, when I define that attribute as index in slapd.conf, I can retrieve data that I am looking for.

Comment: So index it. You do understand that an unindexed search searches the entire directory?